# CSS animation NOT executing in Mozilla using mozAnimationName

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

```
<style>

@keyframes shake {
    0% {
        -moz-transform:scale(0);opacity:0;
    }
    25% {
        -moz-transform:scale(1.3);opacity:1;
    }
    50% {
        -moz-transform:scale(0.7);opacity:1;
    }
    75% {
        -moz-transform:scale(2);opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform:scale(1);opacity:1;-moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    }
}


</style>

<div style="-moz-animation-duration:2s;" onclick='this.style.mozAnimationName="shake";'>TEST</div>
```

It works fine in Google Chrome with its respective `-webkit` prefix, but with Firefox (`-moz`), it doesn't function properly.

Is there a solution for this, or is this simply a dumb mistake on my part? Furthermore, I do not want to utilize jQuery for my solution.

Comment: `this.style.mozAnimationName = 'shake';` perhaps?

Comment: Edited my post. Same problem still applies though. @phil I just edited it accidentally earlier with it's CSS equivalent.

Comment: Can you put together a JSFiddle? Also, try just `style.animationName`

Comment: Sure thing mate. @Phil http://jsfiddle.net/zhr2cqqx/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because [Firefox no longer requires the vendor prefixes in more recent versions](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) (starting from Firefox 16), so just drop those:

http://jsfiddle.net/nsca73oo/2/

```
<style>

@keyframes shake {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity:0;
    }
    25% {
        transform: scale(1.3);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(0.7);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    75% {
        transform: scale(2);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
}


</style>

<div style="animation-duration: 2s;" onclick='this.style.animationName = "shake";'>TEST</div>
```

Comment: I feel like I'm a special kind of idiot... but why don't they have backward-compatibility with those prefixes? It seems a bit odd to me.

Comment: They might have supported both under some versions, so that they could transition into no-prefix only, I'm not sure though, I'll see if I can find anything on that. Here you can check out the version history and when they stopped requiring the prefix: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation. Click on "Show All". And don't worry, I hadn't realized that either until a while ago. What I started doing, and I'd recommend, is using [prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/), so you don't have to worry about stuff like that.

Comment: Holy smokes `prefix-free` is incredible! Where do you hear about this stuff? I'm going to use it right now, I have massive CSS3-dependent stylesheets!

Comment: I don't actually remember haha, but there are many ways to solve the prefix issue, I agree that that one is pretty awesome.  I think there are also 'pre-processors' that will automatically add the prefixes.